# Wordle check logic

Tags: javascript, html, web, sass

I am trying to make a wordle clone, but i am facing error in logic checking of guess.
here i am denoting grey as absent, yellow as present, green as correct.
Suppose my solution word is "cried".
First guess: "kneel" output: "aaaca"
but my second guess is "mouse" it should be "aaaap" but it is showing all absent.

It retrieves the guessed word and the letters at the given position in the guessed word and the solution word.
If the guessed letter is the same as the solution letter, it marks the letter as correctly guessed and schedules a call to revealTile with the status 'correct'.
If the guessed letter is not the same as the solution letter, it checks if the guessed letter is present anywhere in the solution word and hasn't been correctly guessed yet. If it is, it schedules a call to revealTile with the status 'present'. If it's not, it schedules a call to revealTile with the status 'absent'.
The setTimeout calls are used to delay the revealing of the tiles, with each tile being revealed 150 milliseconds after the previous one.

```
let matchedPositions = [];
  let correctlyGuessedLetters = new Array(5).fill(null);

const checkLetter = (position, currentGuessCount) => {
  let guessedWord = currentGuess.dataset.letters;
  let guessLetter = guessedWord.charAt(position);
  let solutionLetter = solution.charAt(position);

  if (guessLetter == solutionLetter) {
    correctlyGuessedLetters[position] = guessLetter;
    setTimeout(() => {
      revealTile(position, 'correct', currentGuessCount);
      currentGuessCount++;
    }, position * 150);
  } else {
    let isPresent = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (guessLetter == solution.charAt(i) && correctlyGuessedLetters[i] !== guessLetter) {
        isPresent = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (isPresent) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        revealTile(position, 'present', currentGuessCount);
        currentGuessCount++;
      }, position * 150);
    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {
        revealTile(position, 'absent', currentGuessCount);
        currentGuessCount++;
      }, position * 150);
    }
  }
};
```

[my github](https://github.com/IndranilMajee/wordle-clone/blob/main/app/js/script.js)

I want the next guess to have same feautures as previous one